# How to scatter plot pairs of columns in subplots and color markers by a column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, subplot

I want to generate simple scatter plots **dots with two color's** for set of factors in ~100 samples generated from two different platforms to see the correlation of each factors.

Looking **python3** using pandas, matplotlib with features x, y axis  scale ranges, different color for data points per platform, size with 1. all the nine data plots in single image file (multi window) using loop and 2. each plot in a separate file. Thanks in advance for any help.
I tried the following basic steps to generate plot per data.

```
import pandas as pd
#import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("test_data_np_arg.csv")
df.head()
    Samples      yield_NP   mean_NP    pct_NP  mad_NP  pct-act_NP  pct-pp_NP  mean_NP.1  insert_NP       rate_NP     yield_Arg  mean_Arg  pct_Arg  mad_Arg  pct-act_Arg  pct-pp_Arg  mean_Arg.1  insert_Arg  rate_Arg
0  sample_1  1.020000e+11  30.85476  95.83108    2.40    99.72261   97.95775      440.6       99.7  5.970000e-09  1.019400e+11  30.30078  95.7618        4     99.72261    97.95775       440.6        99.7         0
1  sample_2  1.350000e+11  39.54372  96.13075    2.69    99.73480   97.92363      446.7      103.7  1.120000e-06  1.348150e+11  38.89375  96.2904        5     99.73480    97.92363       446.7       103.7         0
2  sample_3  1.040000e+11  31.50230  95.87788    2.53    99.79733   98.28176      450.1      101.8  3.980000e-06  1.043480e+11  30.95051  95.8694        5     99.79733    98.28176       450.1       101.8         0
3  sample_4  1.080000e+11  32.88599  95.94028    2.58    99.80831   98.33480      452.7      102.2  1.351000e-06  1.080160e+11  32.25406  95.9667        5     99.80831    98.33480       452.7       102.2         0
4  sample_5  1.070000e+11  30.95200  95.87643    2.85    99.73196   97.89158      436.1       99.2  1.280000e-06  1.069150e+11  30.45470  95.8471        5     99.73196    97.89158       436.1        99.2         0

###x = range(100)
###y = range(100)
### X-axis limits
###xmin = 1e-4;
###xmax = 3e-3;
###plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,2])
###df.plot(kind = 'scatter', x = 'yield_NP', y = 'yeild_Arg')
###plt.scatter(yield_NP,yield_Arg) #line graph

x = df['yield_NP']
y = df['yield_Arg']
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xlabel()
plt.ylabel()
plt.title()
plt.scatter(x,y,color='blue')
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(10,8), 'figure.dpi':100})
plt.show()
```

Example:

My data in **.csv** format file attached.
The 100 samples are in a rows and each factors (values) from two different platforms named **NP** and **Arg** are in the column.

**Header:**
column1 Samples

**platform NP:**
column 2 to 10 yield_NP mean_NP,pct_NP,mad_NP,pct-act_NP,pct-pp_NP,mean_NP,insert_NP,rate_NP

**platform Arg:**
column 11 to 19 yield_Arg,mean_Arg,pct_Arg,mad_Arg,pct-act_Arg,pct-pp_Arg,mean_Arg,insert_Arg,rate_Arg

1. scatter plot “yield” should be of column **yield_NP vs column yield_Arg**, OR (col 2 vs 11)
2. scatter plot “mean” should be of column **mean_NP vs column mean_Arg**, (col 3 vs 12)
3. …
   ....
4. …

**input data** `test_data_np_arg.csv`

```
Samples yield_NP    mean_NP pct_NP  mad_NP  pct-act_NP  pct-pp_NP   mean_NP insert_NP   rate_NP yield_Arg   mean_Arg    pct_Arg mad_Arg pct-act_Arg pct-pp_Arg  mean_Arg    insert_Arg  rate_Arg
sample_1    1.02E+11    30.85476    95.83108    2.4 99.72261    97.95775    440.6   99.7    5.97E-09    1.0194E+11  30.30078    95.7618 4   99.72261    97.95775    440.6   99.7    0
sample_2    1.35E+11    39.54372    96.13075    2.69    99.7348 97.92363    446.7   103.7   1.12E-06    1.34815E+11 38.89375    96.2904 5   99.7348 97.92363    446.7   103.7   0
sample_3    1.04E+11    31.5023 95.87788    2.53    99.79733    98.28176    450.1   101.8   3.98E-06    1.04348E+11 30.95051    95.8694 5   99.79733    98.28176    450.1   101.8   0
sample_4    1.08E+11    32.88599    95.94028    2.58    99.80831    98.3348 452.7   102.2   0.000001351 1.08016E+11 32.25406    95.9667 5   99.80831    98.3348 452.7   102.2   0
sample_5    1.07E+11    30.952  95.87643    2.85    99.73196    97.89158    436.1   99.2    1.28E-06    1.06915E+11 30.4547 95.8471 5   99.73196    97.89158    436.1   99.2    0
sample_6    1.02E+11    30.32588    95.82636    2.32    99.74506    98.09959    443.9   99.4    3.82E-09    1.01891E+11 29.77961    95.7173 4   99.74506    98.09959    443.9   99.4    0
sample_7    1.03E+11    30.8906 95.87171    2.41    99.72588    97.97383    442.1   99.5    7.48E-07    1.02859E+11 30.33201    95.8008 4   99.72588    97.97383    442.1   99.5    0
sample_8    1.05E+11    32.29805    95.91017    2.54    99.78956    98.12378    447.3   100.8   1.63E-06    1.04712E+11 31.69718    95.9272 5   99.78956    98.12378    447.3   100.8   0
sample_9    98732711940 29.64056    95.79516    2.26    99.73939    97.91273    437.9   97.7    2.95E-09    98732711940 29.11294    95.6311 4   99.73939    97.91273    437.9   97.7    0
sample_10   1.02E+11    30.22417    95.78791    2.41    99.69657    97.78881    437.3   97.8    1.92E-06    1.01992E+11 29.69243    95.6681 4   99.69657    97.78881    437.3   97.8    0
sample_11   1.77E+11    52.53136    96.31651    3.73    99.74559    98.03557    440.9   100.9   7.83E-07    1.7654E+11  51.61069    96.5147 6   99.74559    98.03557    440.9   100.9   0
sample_12   1.20E+11    35.07535    95.99761    2.87    99.76128    98.045  432.6   100.8   1.31E-06    1.19786E+11 34.61427    96.1337 5   99.76128    98.045  432.6   100.8   0
sample_13   98874217002 29.67494    95.79408    2.28    99.74523    97.95379    445.2   99.5    6.72E-09    98874217002 29.14371    95.6212 4   99.74523    97.95379    445.2   99.5    0
sample_14   1.09E+11    32.06474    95.89239    2.47    99.71998    97.89142    443.9   99.9    1.05E-06    1.0895E+11  31.49802    95.8792 5   99.71998    97.89142    443.9   99.9    0
sample_15   1.00E+11    29.80763    95.78573    2.42    99.75593    97.87908    435.1   99.1    2.39E-09    1.00279E+11 29.29912    95.6557 4   99.75593    97.87908    435.1   99.1    0
sample_16   1.09E+11    32.91384    95.90146    2.51    99.70689    97.85116    445.6   100.7   1.88E-06    1.09404E+11 32.29913    95.9107 5   99.70689    97.85116    445.6   100.7   0
sample_17   97816752073 28.99877    95.80532    2.52    99.77984    98.11997    426.5   99.9    3.42E-09    97816752073 28.57639    95.6557 4   99.77984    98.11997    426.5   99.9    0
sample_18   99875608784 29.8512 95.84741    2.3 99.77063    98.227  443.8   99  3.90E-10    99875608784 29.30749    95.7026 4   99.77063    98.227  443.8   99  0
sample_19   1.05E+11    31.18936    95.8826 2.51    99.71659    97.8446 443.5   101 4.05E-09    1.05462E+11 30.71611    95.8931 4   99.71659    97.8446 443.5   101 0
sample_20   1.14E+11    34.54803    95.99543    2.5 99.73037    97.95208    446.9   100.4   3.05E-09    1.14368E+11 33.94012    96.0641 5   99.73037    97.95208    446.9   100.4   0
sample_21   91070755092 28.08189    95.69757    2.39    99.49053    97.29799    424.5   97.7    7.58E-10    91070755092 27.16736    95.1967 4   99.49053    97.29799    424.5   97.7    0
sample_22   1.03E+11    30.18906    95.80496    2.32    99.7367 98.0612 444 99.9    1.45E-06    1.02681E+11 29.65553    95.6822 4   99.7367 98.0612 444 99.9    0
sample_23   94779004959 28.32233    95.74401    2.26    99.75454    98.06741    440.1   101.9   4.55E-09    94779004959 27.79295    95.4909 4   99.75454    98.06741    440.1   101.9   0
sample_24   1.10E+11    32.6702 95.93303    2.45    99.79297    98.24325    458 102.7   2.48E-09    1.09683E+11 32.10852    95.947  5   99.79297    98.24325    458 102.7   0
sample_25   1.10E+11    32.51392    95.91561    2.58    99.69296    97.88712    438.9   100.3   8.80E-07    1.09664E+11 31.98217    95.9614 5   99.69296    97.88712    438.9   100.3   0
sample_26   1.11E+11    33.18012    95.9421 2.51    99.68512    97.88962    449.1   103.5   3.25E-09    1.10539E+11 32.59671    96.0175 5   99.68512    97.88962    449.1   103.5   0
sample_27   1.09E+11    31.75891    95.89965    2.54    99.74522    97.79328    439.7   99.9    2.67E-09    1.0945E+11  31.30704    95.9617 5   99.74522    97.79328    439.7   99.9    0
sample_28   1.07E+11    32.02777    95.92396    2.57    99.72103    97.78891    454 104.8   9.02E-09    1.07001E+11 31.52126    95.959  5   99.72103    97.78891    454 104.8   0
sample_29   1.12E+11    33.64239    95.93847    2.7 99.74315    97.92744    447.5   103.1   4.11E-09    1.11869E+11 33.10581    96.0227 5   99.74315    97.92744    447.5   103.1   0
sample_30   1.12E+11    32.99544    95.93774    2.53    99.73674    97.98786    442.8   100.9   1.20E-06    1.12014E+11 32.51   96.0109 5   99.73674    97.98786    442.8   100.9   0
sample_31   1.05E+11    32.27342    95.90836    2.44    99.72944    98.04976    441.8   100.3   1.47E-06    1.04834E+11 31.37597    95.8615 4   99.72944    98.04976    441.8   100.3   0
sample_32   1.08E+11    31.67663    95.87933    2.51    99.74561    97.88388    435.8   99.6    8.24E-07    1.08499E+11 31.18913    95.9151 4   99.74561    97.88388    435.8   99.6    0
sample_33   1.12E+11    32.50864    95.92867    2.61    99.68827    97.78834    449.6   102.8   9.57E-09    1.11538E+11 31.97458    95.9779 5   99.68827    97.78834    449.6   102.8   0
sample_34   1.13E+11    34.29474    96.00631    2.78    99.83226    98.27716    446.4   101.6   2.75E-09    1.12849E+11 33.82919    96.1052 5   99.83226    98.27716    446.4   101.6   0
sample_35   99400525623 30.81942    95.8387 2.48    99.78345    98.20671    446 101.2   1.08E-06    99400525623 29.98714    95.7308 4   99.78345    98.20671    446 101.2   0
sample_36   1.15E+11    34.29637    95.97148    2.82    99.77035    98.02257    441.1   101.1   1.04E-06    1.14885E+11 33.74547    96.0615 5   99.77035    98.02257    441.1   101.1   0
sample_37   1.07E+11    32.37888    95.9508 2.61    99.7133 97.98365    444.5   100.5   1.34E-09    1.07473E+11 31.76157    95.9864 5   99.7133 97.98365    444.5   100.5   0
sample_38   1.03E+11    31.53656    95.93194    2.64    99.77947    98.19387    439.4   101 1.50E-09    1.02917E+11 31.02146    95.951  5   99.77947    98.19387    439.4   101 0
sample_39   1.06E+11    30.28286    95.87534    2.45    99.75018    98.05562    439.9   100.9   1.37E-06    1.05871E+11 29.79179    95.8127 4   99.75018    98.05562    439.9   100.9   0
sample_40   1.05E+11    31.52802    95.91706    2.47    99.79558    98.06771    427.3   98.4    1.18E-08    1.05336E+11 30.91472    95.9214 4   99.79558    98.06771    427.3   98.4    0
sample_40   1.05E+11    31.52802    95.91706    2.47    99.79558    98.06771    427.3   98.4    1.18E-08    1.05336E+11 30.91472    95.9214 4   99.79558    98.06771    427.3   98.4    0
sample_41   1.09E+11    31.29889    95.91489    2.35    99.73194    97.99713    427.2   97.5    9.77E-09    1.0949E+11  30.81643    95.9266 4   99.73194    97.99713    427.2   97.5    0
sample_42   1.03E+11    30.35667    95.89239    2.41    99.73659    98.03721    438.7   101.2   8.28E-07    1.03284E+11 29.88501    95.8842 4   99.73659    98.03721    438.7   101.2   0
sample_43   1.10E+11    32.5761 95.94972    2.74    99.71097    97.89525    454.2   103.2   2.21E-09    1.10059E+11 32.00364    95.9879 5   99.71097    97.89525    454.2   103.2   0
sample_44   1.13E+11    33.22374    96.00668    2.89    99.77643    98.12726    437.6   100 1.59E-09    1.132E+11   32.77427    96.1141 5   99.77643    98.12726    437.6   100 0
sample_45   1.20E+11    34.19891    96.00994    3.05    99.76761    98.08657    444.4   101.3   1.33E-09    1.19803E+11 33.77175    96.1266 5   99.76761    98.08657    444.4   101.3   0
sample_46   1.19E+11    35.68893    96.07089    2.56    99.7517 98.01643    439.8   100.2   2.04E-09    1.19052E+11 35.17978    96.227  5   99.7517 98.01643    439.8   100.2   0
sample_47   1.56E+11    47.59501    96.27841    3.11    99.77304    98.13004    441.7   100.9   5.48E-07    1.55554E+11 46.80516    96.4836 6   99.77304    98.13004    441.7   100.9   0
sample_48   1.28E+11    37.59036    96.09955    2.62    99.7544 98.08099    436.8   100.2   1.94E-09    1.28106E+11 37.08409    96.2848 5   99.7544 98.08099    436.8   100.2   0
sample_49   99660967688 29.62502    95.82274    2.36    99.76129    98.06697    424.5   99.1    1.82E-09    99660967688 29.11601    95.6862 4   99.76129    98.06697    424.5   99.1    0
sample_50   1.10E+11    32.38506    95.96205    2.4 99.73501    98.05385    442.5   101.1   3.24E-09    1.10417E+11 31.8706 96.0418 4   99.73501    98.05385    442.5   101.1   0
sample_51   1.01E+11    30.60525    95.90146    2.37    99.71151    97.85232    440.7   101 4.59E-06    1.00502E+11 30.02358    95.8872 4   99.71151    97.85232    440.7   101 0
sample_52   1.21E+11    36.92763    96.11334    2.85    99.693  97.84396    428.1   99.3    8.65E-07    1.20533E+11 35.97378    96.2246 5   99.693  97.84396    428.1   99.3    0
sample_53   1.12E+11    31.55724    95.92106    2.5 99.71733    97.94133    427.6   96.6    7.64E-10    1.11613E+11 31.0624 95.9483 4   99.71733    97.94133    427.6   96.6    0
sample_54   1.10E+11    34.16102    96.00414    2.69    99.72714    98.20101    434 99.7    5.51E-06    1.10452E+11 33.24734    96.0308 5   99.72714    98.20101    434 99.7    0
sample_55   1.08E+11    30.76239    95.87498    2.76    99.80626    98.26043    434.2   99.4    1.75E-09    1.07891E+11 30.31996    95.8528 5   99.80626    98.26043    434.2   99.4    0
sample_56   1.02E+11    31.01334    95.8884 2.44    99.71137    98.02674    438.1   100.1   4.23E-10    1.01508E+11 30.26782    95.8255 4   99.71137    98.02674    438.1   100.1   0
sample_57   1.10E+11    32.27204    95.93738    2.77    99.74261    98.04745    425.5   96.9    1.02E-06    1.09992E+11 31.78231    95.998  5   99.74261    98.04745    425.5   96.9    0
sample_58   1.01E+11    29.63566    95.83362    2.49    99.73006    98.03498    429.5   98.5    1.75E-09    1.01204E+11 29.13839    95.7239 4   99.73006    98.03498    429.5   98.5    0
sample_59   1.39E+11    41.53544    96.18445    2.95    99.8092 98.30391    436.1   101 7.78E-07    1.38829E+11 40.87246    96.3519 5   99.8092 98.30391    436.1   101 0
sample_60   1.49E+11    43.58239    96.22036    3.1 99.7331 98.18926    441.1   101.4   1.45E-06    1.48519E+11 42.89485    96.407  5   99.7331 98.18926    441.1   101.4   0
sample_61   94358139331 29.02033    95.80859    2.23    99.72827    98.04585    442.6   102 3.49E-09    94358139331 28.40806    95.5737 4   99.72827    98.04585    442.6   102 0
sample_62   1.02E+11    30.73124    95.88949    2.55    99.75763    98.1358 440.8   101 1.91E-08    1.01922E+11 30.14433    95.8251 4   99.75763    98.1358 440.8   101 0
sample_63   1.01E+11    30.26892    95.83543    2.38    99.7678 98.10769    440.7   101.3   1.58E-06    1.01125E+11 29.77872    95.7721 4   99.7678 98.10769    440.7   101.3   0
sample_64   1.08E+11    31.847  95.94573    2.5 99.72622    97.99772    433.5   97.6    1.79E-06    1.0784E+11  31.35237    95.991  4   99.72622    97.99772    433.5   97.6    0
sample_65   96776159556 30.06908    95.84777    2.45    99.52316    97.58877    422.8   98  1.25E-09    96776159556 29.2151 95.6652 4   99.52316    97.58877    422.8   98  0
sample_66   1.26E+11    37.48715    96.11951    2.79    99.74966    98.10085    430.1   99.5    3.11E-09    1.25599E+11 36.84727    96.2503 5   99.74966    98.10085    430.1   99.5    0
sample_67   1.31E+11    39.26691    96.14926    3.08    99.74451    97.95533    432 100.3   8.28E-07    1.31475E+11 38.58257    96.2912 5   99.74451    97.95533    432 100.3   0
sample_68   99308534044 29.89997    95.8387 2.41    99.79687    98.15405    434.1   100.5   4.05E-09    99308534044 29.4153 95.755  4   99.79687    98.15405    434.1   100.5   0
sample_69   1.04E+11    31.11425    95.90001    2.53    99.75409    98.01168    430.9   99  6.05E-07    1.04154E+11 30.60253    95.8799 4   99.75409    98.01168    430.9   99  0
sample_70   1.20E+11    36.34303    96.09302    2.69    99.75035    97.97297    437.9   101.2   4.16E-09    1.19703E+11 35.73808    96.2123 5   99.75035    97.97297    437.9   101.2   0
sample_71   1.72E+11    51.99843    96.35387    3.62    99.745  98.13036    435.3   100.3   4.90E-07    1.72425E+11 51.06496    96.5405 6   99.745  98.13036    435.3   100.3   0
sample_72   1.00E+11    30.48683    95.86119    2.45    99.70088    97.77195    433.9   98.2    2.17E-09    1.0005E+11  29.95496    95.795  4   99.70088    97.77195    433.9   98.2    0
sample_73   1.02E+11    30.7607 95.9011 2.51    99.70653    97.88851    424.1   98.2    4.36E-09    1.02104E+11 30.15563    95.8511 4   99.70653    97.88851    424.1   98.2    0
sample_74   1.12E+11    32.35504    95.93339    2.43    99.72186    97.94937    431.1   97.9    6.83E-10    1.12015E+11 31.8753 96.0092 4   99.72186    97.94937    431.1   97.9    0
sample_75   1.55E+11    46.32393    96.26027    3.47    99.75905    98.11215    422 98  1.10E-06    1.55011E+11 45.5614 96.4486 6   99.75905    98.11215    422 98  0
sample_76   97089503358 29.48785    95.82201    2.86    99.74503    97.916  434.2   99.3    8.99E-09    97089503358 28.95893    95.6086 5   99.74503    97.916  434.2   99.3    0
sample_77   1.09E+11    32.97904    95.97475    2.63    99.71645    97.81641    437.2   100.9   1.95E-06    1.09002E+11 32.38335    96.0309 5   99.71645    97.81641    437.2   100.9   0
sample_78   1.03E+11    30.14343    95.87208    2.51    99.72748    97.94631    431.7   98.7    1.47E-09    1.02866E+11 29.69167    95.8327 4   99.72748    97.94631    431.7   98.7    0
sample_79   1.02E+11    30.40873    95.86446    2.43    99.74403    98.04649    437.3   99.9    1.50E-06    1.02082E+11 29.92895    95.8244 4   99.74403    98.04649    437.3   99.9    0
sample_80   1.25E+11    37.91671    96.09157    2.74    99.74695    98.07409    440.2   101 1.56E-06    1.25097E+11 37.29407    96.2274 5   99.74695    98.07409    440.2   101 0
sample_81   1.01E+11    31.53161    95.90328    3.29    99.71049    97.88596    433.1   100.6   9.41E-07    1.01411E+11 30.83368    95.8225 5   99.71049    97.88596    433.1   100.6   0
sample_82   99173169979 29.89573    95.85684    2.47    99.74151    98.05292    437.1   101 1.35E-09    99173169979 29.40804    95.7447 4   99.74151    98.05292    437.1   101 0
sample_83   1.04E+11    30.49102    95.88768    2.7 99.73246    97.92362    425.7   96.3    8.54E-09    1.04393E+11 30.01485    95.8424 5   99.73246    97.92362    425.7   96.3    0
sample_84   97704382884 29.88968    95.84995    2.4 99.78704    98.23961    441.2   102 4.37E-09    97704382884 29.30928    95.7342 4   99.78704    98.23961    441.2   102 0
sample_85   1.15E+11    33.95192    95.99579    2.86    99.7469 98.20643    435.9   99.7    2.10E-06    1.14548E+11 33.36085    96.0645 5   99.7469 98.20643    435.9   99.7    0
sample_86   1.06E+11    30.3987 95.86954    2.49    99.73811    98.12377    437.2   99.8    3.98E-09    1.06286E+11 29.92345    95.8407 4   99.73811    98.12377    437.2   99.8    0
sample_87   1.11E+11    33.99411    95.99688    2.66    99.76458    98.1613 445 101.6   1.01E-08    1.10903E+11 33.40791    96.0659 5   99.76458    98.1613 445 101.6   0
sample_88   1.07E+11    32.28092    95.95407    2.5 99.74595    98.01535    433.9   100.6   5.82E-09    1.0669E+11  31.62522    95.9834 5   99.74595    98.01535    433.9   100.6   0
sample_89   1.12E+11    33.36572    95.98309    2.61    99.76743    98.11891    437.2   101.1   1.30E-09    1.12314E+11 32.8189 96.0525 5   99.76743    98.11891    437.2   101.1   0
sample_90   1.03E+11    30.42415    95.88804    2.43    99.52558    97.59924    418.2   95  8.03E-10    1.02866E+11 29.75168    95.8063 4   99.52558    97.59924    418.2   95  0
sample_91   1.26E+11    38.03029    96.1166 3.75    99.76455    98.16839    432.9   99.6    1.07E-06    1.25675E+11 37.41665    96.2519 5   99.76455    98.16839    432.9   99.6    0
sample_92   1.32E+11    39.33902    96.14345    2.77    99.78796    98.27147    425.6   98.8    3.83E-09    1.31768E+11 38.7008 96.3025 5   99.78796    98.27147    425.6   98.8    0
sample_93   99266572540 28.77619    95.8075 2.43    99.7336 98.01659    433.9   99.1    4.99E-09    99266572540 28.32761    95.6002 4   99.7336 98.01659    433.9   99.1    0
sample_94   1.06E+11    31.0585 95.89747    2.57    99.77842    98.20429    439.6   100 2.41E-09    1.06262E+11 30.5643 95.898  4   99.77842    98.20429    439.6   100 0
sample_95   1.39E+11    41.76222    96.20041    3.13    99.70977    98.06093    451.8   104 3.40E-09    1.38828E+11 41.01108    96.3587 5   99.70977    98.06093    451.8   104 0
sample_96   1.13E+11    34.08653    95.99108    2.54    99.79491    98.17081    435.9   99  2.31E-09    1.13469E+11 33.5711 96.0856 5   99.79491    98.17081    435.9   99  0
sample_97   1.00E+11    29.98517    95.86627    2.38    99.73274    98.04362    439.6   101.7   6.33E-09    1.00316E+11 29.38303    95.7557 4   99.73274    98.04362    439.6   101.7   0
sample_98   1.14E+11    34.66174    96.01937    2.62    99.73272    98.02972    439.7   101.8   9.26E-09    1.13837E+11 33.81398    96.0889 5   99.73272    98.02972    439.7   101.8   0
sample_99   1.22E+11    36.80748    96.08722    2.73    99.70917    98.05788    441.4   101.9   1.41E-09    1.21809E+11 36.10285    96.1936 5   99.70917    98.05788    441.4   101.9   0
sample_100  1.26E+11    37.63943    96.09338    2.8 99.77074    98.15844    451.1   104.1   1.54E-06    1.25873E+11 36.97827    96.2291 5   99.77074    98.15844    451.1   104.1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

- Slice the columns into groups based on `x` and `y`, such that the order of each list corresponds to `xy` pairs, and then `zip` the groups together.
- In order to separate the points by a metric, it's easiest to use [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) with the `hue` parameter.

  - Coloring the points, by `'Samples'`, is not useful because there are too many unique categories.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the xy groups
colx_pairs = df.columns[1:10]
coly_pairs = df.columns[10:20]

col_pairs = list(zip(colx_pairs, coly_pairs))

# create a figure with 9 subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(16, 10), tight_layout=True)

# flatten the 3 x 3 axes array for easy iteration
axes = axes.flatten()

# iterate through each ax in axes, and the corresponding xy pair
for ax, (x, y) in zip(axes, col_pairs):

    # plot the data
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, hue='Samples', ax=ax)
    
    # remove all except the last legend
    if ax != axes[8]:
        ax.get_legend().remove()

# extract the legend handles and labels
handles, labels = axes[8].get_legend_handles_labels()
# create a single figure plot
fig.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False, ncols=5)
# remove the legend from axes[8]
axes[8].get_legend().remove()

fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

[image]

---

- Plotting without regard to coloring by `Samples`.

```py
# create the xy groups
colx_pairs = df.columns[1:10]
coly_pairs = df.columns[10:20]

col_pairs = list(zip(colx_pairs, coly_pairs))

# create a figure with 9 subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(16, 10), tight_layout=True)

# flatten the 3 x 3 axes array for easy iteration
axes = axes.flatten()

# iterate through each ax in axes, and the corresponding xy pair
for ax, (x, y) in zip(axes, col_pairs):

    df.plot(kind='scatter', x=x, y=y, ax=ax, marker='.')

fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

[image]

---

### `df`

```py
data =\
{'Samples': ['sample_1', 'sample_2', 'sample_3', 'sample_4', 'sample_5', 'sample_6', 'sample_7', 'sample_8', 'sample_9', 'sample_10', 'sample_11', 'sample_12', 'sample_13', 'sample_14', 'sample_15', 'sample_16', 'sample_17', 'sample_18', 'sample_19', 'sample_20', 'sample_21', 'sample_22', 'sample_23', 'sample_24', 'sample_25', 'sample_26', 'sample_27', 'sample_28', 'sample_29', 'sample_30', 'sample_31', 'sample_32', 'sample_33', 'sample_34', 'sample_35', 'sample_36', 'sample_37', 'sample_38', 'sample_39', 'sample_40', 'sample_40', 'sample_41', 'sample_42', 'sample_43', 'sample_44', 'sample_45', 'sample_46', 'sample_47', 'sample_48', 'sample_49', 'sample_50', 'sample_51', 'sample_52', 'sample_53', 'sample_54', 'sample_55', 'sample_56', 'sample_57', 'sample_58', 'sample_59', 'sample_60', 'sample_61', 'sample_62', 'sample_63', 'sample_64', 'sample_65', 'sample_66', 'sample_67', 'sample_68', 'sample_69', 'sample_70', 'sample_71', 'sample_72', 'sample_73', 'sample_74', 'sample_75', 'sample_76', 'sample_77', 'sample_78', 'sample_79', 'sample_80', 'sample_81', 'sample_82', 'sample_83', 'sample_84', 'sample_85', 'sample_86', 'sample_87', 'sample_88', 'sample_89', 'sample_90', 'sample_91', 'sample_92', 'sample_93', 'sample_94', 'sample_95', 'sample_96', 'sample_97', 'sample_98', 'sample_99', 'sample_100'],
 'yield_NP': [102000000000.0, 135000000000.0, 104000000000.0, 108000000000.0, 107000000000.0, 102000000000.0, 103000000000.0, 105000000000.0, 98732711940.0, 102000000000.0, 177000000000.0, 120000000000.0, 98874217002.0, 109000000000.0, 100000000000.0, 109000000000.0, 97816752073.0, 99875608784.0, 105000000000.0, 114000000000.0, 91070755092.0, 103000000000.0, 94779004959.0, 110000000000.0, 110000000000.0, 111000000000.0, 109000000000.0, 107000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 105000000000.0, 108000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 113000000000.0, 99400525623.0, 115000000000.0, 107000000000.0, 103000000000.0, 106000000000.0, 105000000000.0, 105000000000.0, 109000000000.0, 103000000000.0, 110000000000.0, 113000000000.0, 120000000000.0, 119000000000.0, 156000000000.0, 128000000000.0, 99660967688.0, 110000000000.0, 101000000000.0, 121000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 110000000000.0, 108000000000.0, 102000000000.0, 110000000000.0, 101000000000.0, 139000000000.0, 149000000000.0, 94358139331.0, 102000000000.0, 101000000000.0, 108000000000.0, 96776159556.0, 126000000000.0, 131000000000.0, 99308534044.0, 104000000000.0, 120000000000.0, 172000000000.0, 100000000000.0, 102000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 155000000000.0, 97089503358.0, 109000000000.0, 103000000000.0, 102000000000.0, 125000000000.0, 101000000000.0, 99173169979.0, 104000000000.0, 97704382884.0, 115000000000.0, 106000000000.0, 111000000000.0, 107000000000.0, 112000000000.0, 103000000000.0, 126000000000.0, 132000000000.0, 99266572540.0, 106000000000.0, 139000000000.0, 113000000000.0, 100000000000.0, 114000000000.0, 122000000000.0, 126000000000.0],
 'mean_NP': [30.85476, 39.54372, 31.5023, 32.88599, 30.952, 30.32588, 30.8906, 32.29805, 29.64056, 30.22417, 52.53136, 35.07535, 29.67494, 32.06474, 29.80763, 32.91384, 28.99877, 29.8512, 31.18936, 34.54803, 28.08189, 30.18906, 28.32233, 32.6702, 32.51392, 33.18012, 31.75891, 32.02777, 33.64239, 32.99544, 32.27342, 31.67663, 32.50864, 34.29474, 30.81942, 34.29637, 32.37888, 31.53656, 30.28286, 31.52802, 31.52802, 31.29889, 30.35667, 32.5761, 33.22374, 34.19891, 35.68893, 47.59501, 37.59036, 29.62502, 32.38506, 30.60525, 36.92763, 31.55724, 34.16102, 30.76239, 31.01334, 32.27204, 29.63566, 41.53544, 43.58239, 29.02033, 30.73124, 30.26892, 31.847, 30.06908, 37.48715, 39.26691, 29.89997, 31.11425, 36.34303, 51.99843, 30.48683, 30.7607, 32.35504, 46.32393, 29.48785, 32.97904, 30.14343, 30.40873, 37.91671, 31.53161, 29.89573, 30.49102, 29.88968, 33.95192, 30.3987, 33.99411, 32.28092, 33.36572, 30.42415, 38.03029, 39.33902, 28.77619, 31.0585, 41.76222, 34.08653, 29.98517, 34.66174, 36.80748, 37.63943],
 'pct_NP': [95.83108, 96.13075, 95.87788, 95.94028, 95.87643, 95.82636, 95.87171, 95.91017, 95.79516, 95.78791, 96.31651, 95.99761, 95.79408, 95.89239, 95.78573, 95.90146, 95.80532, 95.84741, 95.8826, 95.99543, 95.69757, 95.80496, 95.74401, 95.93303, 95.91561, 95.9421, 95.89965, 95.92396, 95.93847, 95.93774, 95.90836, 95.87933, 95.92867, 96.00631, 95.8387, 95.97148, 95.9508, 95.93194, 95.87534, 95.91706, 95.91706, 95.91489, 95.89239, 95.94972, 96.00668, 96.00994, 96.07089, 96.27841, 96.09955, 95.82274, 95.96205, 95.90146, 96.11334, 95.92106, 96.00414, 95.87498, 95.8884, 95.93738, 95.83362, 96.18445, 96.22036, 95.80859, 95.88949, 95.83543, 95.94573, 95.84777, 96.11951, 96.14926, 95.8387, 95.90001, 96.09302, 96.35387, 95.86119, 95.9011, 95.93339, 96.26027, 95.82201, 95.97475, 95.87208, 95.86446, 96.09157, 95.90328, 95.85684, 95.88768, 95.84995, 95.99579, 95.86954, 95.99688, 95.95407, 95.98309, 95.88804, 96.1166, 96.14345, 95.8075, 95.89747, 96.20041, 95.99108, 95.86627, 96.01937, 96.08722, 96.09338],
 'mad_NP': [2.4, 2.69, 2.53, 2.58, 2.85, 2.32, 2.41, 2.54, 2.26, 2.41, 3.73, 2.87, 2.28, 2.47, 2.42, 2.51, 2.52, 2.3, 2.51, 2.5, 2.39, 2.32, 2.26, 2.45, 2.58, 2.51, 2.54, 2.57, 2.7, 2.53, 2.44, 2.51, 2.61, 2.78, 2.48, 2.82, 2.61, 2.64, 2.45, 2.47, 2.47, 2.35, 2.41, 2.74, 2.89, 3.05, 2.56, 3.11, 2.62, 2.36, 2.4, 2.37, 2.85, 2.5, 2.69, 2.76, 2.44, 2.77, 2.49, 2.95, 3.1, 2.23, 2.55, 2.38, 2.5, 2.45, 2.79, 3.08, 2.41, 2.53, 2.69, 3.62, 2.45, 2.51, 2.43, 3.47, 2.86, 2.63, 2.51, 2.43, 2.74, 3.29, 2.47, 2.7, 2.4, 2.86, 2.49, 2.66, 2.5, 2.61, 2.43, 3.75, 2.77, 2.43, 2.57, 3.13, 2.54, 2.38, 2.62, 2.73, 2.8],
 'pct-act_NP': [99.72261, 99.7348, 99.79733, 99.80831, 99.73196, 99.74506, 99.72588, 99.78956, 99.73939, 99.69657, 99.74559, 99.76128, 99.74523, 99.71998, 99.75593, 99.70689, 99.77984, 99.77063, 99.71659, 99.73037, 99.49053, 99.7367, 99.75454, 99.79297, 99.69296, 99.68512, 99.74522, 99.72103, 99.74315, 99.73674, 99.72944, 99.74561, 99.68827, 99.83226, 99.78345, 99.77035, 99.7133, 99.77947, 99.75018, 99.79558, 99.79558, 99.73194, 99.73659, 99.71097, 99.77643, 99.76761, 99.7517, 99.77304, 99.7544, 99.76129, 99.73501, 99.71151, 99.693, 99.71733, 99.72714, 99.80626, 99.71137, 99.74261, 99.73006, 99.8092, 99.7331, 99.72827, 99.75763, 99.7678, 99.72622, 99.52316, 99.74966, 99.74451, 99.79687, 99.75409, 99.75035, 99.745, 99.70088, 99.70653, 99.72186, 99.75905, 99.74503, 99.71645, 99.72748, 99.74403, 99.74695, 99.71049, 99.74151, 99.73246, 99.78704, 99.7469, 99.73811, 99.76458, 99.74595, 99.76743, 99.52558, 99.76455, 99.78796, 99.7336, 99.77842, 99.70977, 99.79491, 99.73274, 99.73272, 99.70917, 99.77074],
 'pct-pp_NP': [97.95775, 97.92363, 98.28176, 98.3348, 97.89158, 98.09959, 97.97383, 98.12378, 97.91273, 97.78881, 98.03557, 98.045, 97.95379, 97.89142, 97.87908, 97.85116, 98.11997, 98.227, 97.8446, 97.95208, 97.29799, 98.0612, 98.06741, 98.24325, 97.88712, 97.88962, 97.79328, 97.78891, 97.92744, 97.98786, 98.04976, 97.88388, 97.78834, 98.27716, 98.20671, 98.02257, 97.98365, 98.19387, 98.05562, 98.06771, 98.06771, 97.99713, 98.03721, 97.89525, 98.12726, 98.08657, 98.01643, 98.13004, 98.08099, 98.06697, 98.05385, 97.85232, 97.84396, 97.94133, 98.20101, 98.26043, 98.02674, 98.04745, 98.03498, 98.30391, 98.18926, 98.04585, 98.1358, 98.10769, 97.99772, 97.58877, 98.10085, 97.95533, 98.15405, 98.01168, 97.97297, 98.13036, 97.77195, 97.88851, 97.94937, 98.11215, 97.916, 97.81641, 97.94631, 98.04649, 98.07409, 97.88596, 98.05292, 97.92362, 98.23961, 98.20643, 98.12377, 98.1613, 98.01535, 98.11891, 97.59924, 98.16839, 98.27147, 98.01659, 98.20429, 98.06093, 98.17081, 98.04362, 98.02972, 98.05788, 98.15844],
 'mean_NP.1': [440.6, 446.7, 450.1, 452.7, 436.1, 443.9, 442.1, 447.3, 437.9, 437.3, 440.9, 432.6, 445.2, 443.9, 435.1, 445.6, 426.5, 443.8, 443.5, 446.9, 424.5, 444.0, 440.1, 458.0, 438.9, 449.1, 439.7, 454.0, 447.5, 442.8, 441.8, 435.8, 449.6, 446.4, 446.0, 441.1, 444.5, 439.4, 439.9, 427.3, 427.3, 427.2, 438.7, 454.2, 437.6, 444.4, 439.8, 441.7, 436.8, 424.5, 442.5, 440.7, 428.1, 427.6, 434.0, 434.2, 438.1, 425.5, 429.5, 436.1, 441.1, 442.6, 440.8, 440.7, 433.5, 422.8, 430.1, 432.0, 434.1, 430.9, 437.9, 435.3, 433.9, 424.1, 431.1, 422.0, 434.2, 437.2, 431.7, 437.3, 440.2, 433.1, 437.1, 425.7, 441.2, 435.9, 437.2, 445.0, 433.9, 437.2, 418.2, 432.9, 425.6, 433.9, 439.6, 451.8, 435.9, 439.6, 439.7, 441.4, 451.1],
 'insert_NP': [99.7, 103.7, 101.8, 102.2, 99.2, 99.4, 99.5, 100.8, 97.7, 97.8, 100.9, 100.8, 99.5, 99.9, 99.1, 100.7, 99.9, 99.0, 101.0, 100.4, 97.7, 99.9, 101.9, 102.7, 100.3, 103.5, 99.9, 104.8, 103.1, 100.9, 100.3, 99.6, 102.8, 101.6, 101.2, 101.1, 100.5, 101.0, 100.9, 98.4, 98.4, 97.5, 101.2, 103.2, 100.0, 101.3, 100.2, 100.9, 100.2, 99.1, 101.1, 101.0, 99.3, 96.6, 99.7, 99.4, 100.1, 96.9, 98.5, 101.0, 101.4, 102.0, 101.0, 101.3, 97.6, 98.0, 99.5, 100.3, 100.5, 99.0, 101.2, 100.3, 98.2, 98.2, 97.9, 98.0, 99.3, 100.9, 98.7, 99.9, 101.0, 100.6, 101.0, 96.3, 102.0, 99.7, 99.8, 101.6, 100.6, 101.1, 95.0, 99.6, 98.8, 99.1, 100.0, 104.0, 99.0, 101.7, 101.8, 101.9, 104.1],
 'rate_NP': [5.97e-09, 1.12e-06, 3.98e-06, 1.351e-06, 1.28e-06, 3.82e-09, 7.48e-07, 1.63e-06, 2.95e-09, 1.92e-06, 7.83e-07, 1.31e-06, 6.72e-09, 1.05e-06, 2.39e-09, 1.88e-06, 3.42e-09, 3.9e-10, 4.05e-09, 3.05e-09, 7.58e-10, 1.45e-06, 4.55e-09, 2.48e-09, 8.8e-07, 3.25e-09, 2.67e-09, 9.02e-09, 4.11e-09, 1.2e-06, 1.47e-06, 8.24e-07, 9.57e-09, 2.75e-09, 1.08e-06, 1.04e-06, 1.34e-09, 1.5e-09, 1.37e-06, 1.18e-08, 1.18e-08, 9.77e-09, 8.28e-07, 2.21e-09, 1.59e-09, 1.33e-09, 2.04e-09, 5.48e-07, 1.94e-09, 1.82e-09, 3.24e-09, 4.59e-06, 8.65e-07, 7.64e-10, 5.51e-06, 1.75e-09, 4.23e-10, 1.02e-06, 1.75e-09, 7.78e-07, 1.45e-06, 3.49e-09, 1.91e-08, 1.58e-06, 1.79e-06, 1.25e-09, 3.11e-09, 8.28e-07, 4.05e-09, 6.05e-07, 4.16e-09, 4.9e-07, 2.17e-09, 4.36e-09, 6.83e-10, 1.1e-06, 8.99e-09, 1.95e-06, 1.47e-09, 1.5e-06, 1.56e-06, 9.41e-07, 1.35e-09, 8.54e-09, 4.37e-09, 2.1e-06, 3.98e-09, 1.01e-08, 5.82e-09, 1.3e-09, 8.03e-10, 1.07e-06, 3.83e-09, 4.99e-09, 2.41e-09, 3.4e-09, 2.31e-09, 6.33e-09, 9.26e-09, 1.41e-09, 1.54e-06],
 'yield_Arg': [101940000000.0, 134815000000.0, 104348000000.0, 108016000000.0, 106915000000.0, 101891000000.0, 102859000000.0, 104712000000.0, 98732711940.0, 101992000000.0, 176540000000.0, 119786000000.0, 98874217002.0, 108950000000.0, 100279000000.0, 109404000000.0, 97816752073.0, 99875608784.0, 105462000000.0, 114368000000.0, 91070755092.0, 102681000000.0, 94779004959.0, 109683000000.0, 109664000000.0, 110539000000.0, 109450000000.0, 107001000000.0, 111869000000.0, 112014000000.0, 104834000000.0, 108499000000.0, 111538000000.0, 112849000000.0, 99400525623.0, 114885000000.0, 107473000000.0, 102917000000.0, 105871000000.0, 105336000000.0, 105336000000.0, 109490000000.0, 103284000000.0, 110059000000.0, 113200000000.0, 119803000000.0, 119052000000.0, 155554000000.0, 128106000000.0, 99660967688.0, 110417000000.0, 100502000000.0, 120533000000.0, 111613000000.0, 110452000000.0, 107891000000.0, 101508000000.0, 109992000000.0, 101204000000.0, 138829000000.0, 148519000000.0, 94358139331.0, 101922000000.0, 101125000000.0, 107840000000.0, 96776159556.0, 125599000000.0, 131475000000.0, 99308534044.0, 104154000000.0, 119703000000.0, 172425000000.0, 100050000000.0, 102104000000.0, 112015000000.0, 155011000000.0, 97089503358.0, 109002000000.0, 102866000000.0, 102082000000.0, 125097000000.0, 101411000000.0, 99173169979.0, 104393000000.0, 97704382884.0, 114548000000.0, 106286000000.0, 110903000000.0, 106690000000.0, 112314000000.0, 102866000000.0, 125675000000.0, 131768000000.0, 99266572540.0, 106262000000.0, 138828000000.0, 113469000000.0, 100316000000.0, 113837000000.0, 121809000000.0, 125873000000.0],
 'mean_Arg': [30.30078, 38.89375, 30.95051, 32.25406, 30.4547, 29.77961, 30.33201, 31.69718, 29.11294, 29.69243, 51.61069, 34.61427, 29.14371, 31.49802, 29.29912, 32.29913, 28.57639, 29.30749, 30.71611, 33.94012, 27.16736, 29.65553, 27.79295, 32.10852, 31.98217, 32.59671, 31.30704, 31.52126, 33.10581, 32.51, 31.37597, 31.18913, 31.97458, 33.82919, 29.98714, 33.74547, 31.76157, 31.02146, 29.79179, 30.91472, 30.91472, 30.81643, 29.88501, 32.00364, 32.77427, 33.77175, 35.17978, 46.80516, 37.08409, 29.11601, 31.8706, 30.02358, 35.97378, 31.0624, 33.24734, 30.31996, 30.26782, 31.78231, 29.13839, 40.87246, 42.89485, 28.40806, 30.14433, 29.77872, 31.35237, 29.2151, 36.84727, 38.58257, 29.4153, 30.60253, 35.73808, 51.06496, 29.95496, 30.15563, 31.8753, 45.5614, 28.95893, 32.38335, 29.69167, 29.92895, 37.29407, 30.83368, 29.40804, 30.01485, 29.30928, 33.36085, 29.92345, 33.40791, 31.62522, 32.8189, 29.75168, 37.41665, 38.7008, 28.32761, 30.5643, 41.01108, 33.5711, 29.38303, 33.81398, 36.10285, 36.97827],
 'pct_Arg': [95.7618, 96.2904, 95.8694, 95.9667, 95.8471, 95.7173, 95.8008, 95.9272, 95.6311, 95.6681, 96.5147, 96.1337, 95.6212, 95.8792, 95.6557, 95.9107, 95.6557, 95.7026, 95.8931, 96.0641, 95.1967, 95.6822, 95.4909, 95.947, 95.9614, 96.0175, 95.9617, 95.959, 96.0227, 96.0109, 95.8615, 95.9151, 95.9779, 96.1052, 95.7308, 96.0615, 95.9864, 95.951, 95.8127, 95.9214, 95.9214, 95.9266, 95.8842, 95.9879, 96.1141, 96.1266, 96.227, 96.4836, 96.2848, 95.6862, 96.0418, 95.8872, 96.2246, 95.9483, 96.0308, 95.8528, 95.8255, 95.998, 95.7239, 96.3519, 96.407, 95.5737, 95.8251, 95.7721, 95.991, 95.6652, 96.2503, 96.2912, 95.755, 95.8799, 96.2123, 96.5405, 95.795, 95.8511, 96.0092, 96.4486, 95.6086, 96.0309, 95.8327, 95.8244, 96.2274, 95.8225, 95.7447, 95.8424, 95.7342, 96.0645, 95.8407, 96.0659, 95.9834, 96.0525, 95.8063, 96.2519, 96.3025, 95.6002, 95.898, 96.3587, 96.0856, 95.7557, 96.0889, 96.1936, 96.2291],
 'mad_Arg': [4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5],
 'pct-act_Arg': [99.72261, 99.7348, 99.79733, 99.80831, 99.73196, 99.74506, 99.72588, 99.78956, 99.73939, 99.69657, 99.74559, 99.76128, 99.74523, 99.71998, 99.75593, 99.70689, 99.77984, 99.77063, 99.71659, 99.73037, 99.49053, 99.7367, 99.75454, 99.79297, 99.69296, 99.68512, 99.74522, 99.72103, 99.74315, 99.73674, 99.72944, 99.74561, 99.68827, 99.83226, 99.78345, 99.77035, 99.7133, 99.77947, 99.75018, 99.79558, 99.79558, 99.73194, 99.73659, 99.71097, 99.77643, 99.76761, 99.7517, 99.77304, 99.7544, 99.76129, 99.73501, 99.71151, 99.693, 99.71733, 99.72714, 99.80626, 99.71137, 99.74261, 99.73006, 99.8092, 99.7331, 99.72827, 99.75763, 99.7678, 99.72622, 99.52316, 99.74966, 99.74451, 99.79687, 99.75409, 99.75035, 99.745, 99.70088, 99.70653, 99.72186, 99.75905, 99.74503, 99.71645, 99.72748, 99.74403, 99.74695, 99.71049, 99.74151, 99.73246, 99.78704, 99.7469, 99.73811, 99.76458, 99.74595, 99.76743, 99.52558, 99.76455, 99.78796, 99.7336, 99.77842, 99.70977, 99.79491, 99.73274, 99.73272, 99.70917, 99.77074],
 'pct-pp_Arg': [97.95775, 97.92363, 98.28176, 98.3348, 97.89158, 98.09959, 97.97383, 98.12378, 97.91273, 97.78881, 98.03557, 98.045, 97.95379, 97.89142, 97.87908, 97.85116, 98.11997, 98.227, 97.8446, 97.95208, 97.29799, 98.0612, 98.06741, 98.24325, 97.88712, 97.88962, 97.79328, 97.78891, 97.92744, 97.98786, 98.04976, 97.88388, 97.78834, 98.27716, 98.20671, 98.02257, 97.98365, 98.19387, 98.05562, 98.06771, 98.06771, 97.99713, 98.03721, 97.89525, 98.12726, 98.08657, 98.01643, 98.13004, 98.08099, 98.06697, 98.05385, 97.85232, 97.84396, 97.94133, 98.20101, 98.26043, 98.02674, 98.04745, 98.03498, 98.30391, 98.18926, 98.04585, 98.1358, 98.10769, 97.99772, 97.58877, 98.10085, 97.95533, 98.15405, 98.01168, 97.97297, 98.13036, 97.77195, 97.88851, 97.94937, 98.11215, 97.916, 97.81641, 97.94631, 98.04649, 98.07409, 97.88596, 98.05292, 97.92362, 98.23961, 98.20643, 98.12377, 98.1613, 98.01535, 98.11891, 97.59924, 98.16839, 98.27147, 98.01659, 98.20429, 98.06093, 98.17081, 98.04362, 98.02972, 98.05788, 98.15844],
 'mean_Arg.1': [440.6, 446.7, 450.1, 452.7, 436.1, 443.9, 442.1, 447.3, 437.9, 437.3, 440.9, 432.6, 445.2, 443.9, 435.1, 445.6, 426.5, 443.8, 443.5, 446.9, 424.5, 444.0, 440.1, 458.0, 438.9, 449.1, 439.7, 454.0, 447.5, 442.8, 441.8, 435.8, 449.6, 446.4, 446.0, 441.1, 444.5, 439.4, 439.9, 427.3, 427.3, 427.2, 438.7, 454.2, 437.6, 444.4, 439.8, 441.7, 436.8, 424.5, 442.5, 440.7, 428.1, 427.6, 434.0, 434.2, 438.1, 425.5, 429.5, 436.1, 441.1, 442.6, 440.8, 440.7, 433.5, 422.8, 430.1, 432.0, 434.1, 430.9, 437.9, 435.3, 433.9, 424.1, 431.1, 422.0, 434.2, 437.2, 431.7, 437.3, 440.2, 433.1, 437.1, 425.7, 441.2, 435.9, 437.2, 445.0, 433.9, 437.2, 418.2, 432.9, 425.6, 433.9, 439.6, 451.8, 435.9, 439.6, 439.7, 441.4, 451.1],
 'insert_Arg': [99.7, 103.7, 101.8, 102.2, 99.2, 99.4, 99.5, 100.8, 97.7, 97.8, 100.9, 100.8, 99.5, 99.9, 99.1, 100.7, 99.9, 99.0, 101.0, 100.4, 97.7, 99.9, 101.9, 102.7, 100.3, 103.5, 99.9, 104.8, 103.1, 100.9, 100.3, 99.6, 102.8, 101.6, 101.2, 101.1, 100.5, 101.0, 100.9, 98.4, 98.4, 97.5, 101.2, 103.2, 100.0, 101.3, 100.2, 100.9, 100.2, 99.1, 101.1, 101.0, 99.3, 96.6, 99.7, 99.4, 100.1, 96.9, 98.5, 101.0, 101.4, 102.0, 101.0, 101.3, 97.6, 98.0, 99.5, 100.3, 100.5, 99.0, 101.2, 100.3, 98.2, 98.2, 97.9, 98.0, 99.3, 100.9, 98.7, 99.9, 101.0, 100.6, 101.0, 96.3, 102.0, 99.7, 99.8, 101.6, 100.6, 101.1, 95.0, 99.6, 98.8, 99.1, 100.0, 104.0, 99.0, 101.7, 101.8, 101.9, 104.1],
 'rate_Arg': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```